# Does the wire gauge affect RF emissions when there is a relatively high current?

Tags: current, rf, wire

I'm reviewing wiring in an area that should have minimal RF emissions.

I was wondering if the AC current carrying wires were to experience high current if that could cause RF emissions of significance.  If so would increasing the thickness of the wire help to reduce emissions?

VLF radio is 3 - 30 kHz. AC has 50 and its harmonics, e.g. 100 200 Hz It's low frequency radio, I'd still regard it as RF.

Comment: Is the high current AC at RF frequencies?

Comment: Just standard AC power Line 50/ 60 Hz.

Comment: Question updated.  I was thinking about skin depth etc and whether heating the wire would result in increased vlf radio emissions e.g. https://www.emcrules.com/2017/04/can-incandescent-light-bulbs-cause.html?m=1

Comment: still not clearer: If there's nothing on the line that has high frequencies, where would the emissions ever come from?

Comment: Depends if there wiring is connected to devices that cause conductive EMI in the wires.

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear.  VLF radio is 3 - 30 kHz.  AC has 50 and its harmonics, e.g. 100 200 Hz  It's low frequency radio, I'd still regard it as RF but perhaps my terminology is wrong.

Comment: I added that to your question.

Comment: I don't think the wire gauge specifically affects emissions. But 230 VAC in general tends to do. It's not so much the 50Hz line noise you need to worry about, but misc EMI-generating crap (contactors, motors etc) powered by the power line, giving conducted emissions. Also, these wires generate magnetic field emissions that could cause other weird phenomenon. The rule of thumb is to keep RF electronics clear of mains voltage electronics, antenna wires in particular.

Answer (score 1):

> *I was wondering if the AC current carrying wires were to experience
> high current if that could cause RF emissions of significance. If so
> would increasing the thickness of the wire help to reduce emissions?*

If the RMS AC current is high frequency then it could be regarded as a source of RF emissions. So this is my assumption in answering your sub-question and, of course, if the RMS value increases, then it becomes more of nuisance RF emission source.

But, would increasing the wire diameter abate this noise source; would a thick wire with a naturally reduced current density (compared to a thinner wire carrying the same current) be less of an emitter of RF noise?

The simple answer is no. If you analysed the magnetic field generated at some distance Y from the dead centre of a wire carry X amps, it would be the same irrespective of the diameter of the wire.

We can start to see this in a coaxial cable. We know that if the forward current through the (much thinner) centre wire is the same magnitude as the current returning in the shield, then the external magnetic fields cancel out completely. So we have (a) a thin wire carrying X amps being compared to the shield (a much larger diameter) tube carrying -X amps. They produce the same external magnetic flux density but of opposite polarity and they cancel.

### Scenario 1 - B field around a shield carrying 1000 amps

[image]

### Scenario 2 - B field around a shield with inner carrying 1000 amps

[image]

As you might be able to see (in the corners) the B field values (colours) are the same in both scenarios. Images courtesy of QuickField student edition (a nice little free tool unfortunately limited in finite element analysis nodes but usable in this situation).

It's not much of a step to realize that this would also be the case should the "tube" be actually solid. I have done this FEA analysis but I can't find the picture for when the shield is all copper to the centre. However, there is this picture from [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magin.html) that proclaims the external field to be unrelated to the wire thickness: -

[image]

Where there is a difference is the near field. If the thinner wire is 5 mm diameter and the fatter wire is (say) 10 mm diameter, between 5 mm and 10 mm there will be a measurable field for the thinner wire that can't be measured in the fatter wire (for obvious reasons). I'm not saying the fatter wires doesn't have that field; I'm saying that it is internal to the wire and of no interest when it comes to induction of RF noise.

Answer (score 1):

> VLF radio is 3 - 30 kHz. AC has 50 and its harmonics, e.g. 100 200 Hz It's low frequency radio

Well, if you care about emissions starting at 3 kHz (I kind of doubt that you really care about *emissions* at that low frequency, maybe more about direct coupling, but that's a different question), then you'd need the 3 kHz / 50 Hz = 60th harmonic.

There's physically for all practical purposes no energy in the 60th harmonic in any system that's not designed to produce a high harmonic.

So, no, there's no sensibly measurable RF being emitted from your line, and your thickness doesn't change any of that.

Even if your argument is "things below 3 kHz can still be RF", then you'd still need to consider the efficiency at which your cable transmits something with a wavelength larger than 100 km. (hint: it doesn't, unless you're operating a national power grid, and then you'd need to ask yourself what would be large enough to pick up the transmission – aside from another electrical national grid, and maybe ELF nuclear submarine antennas).